# Google sheet: find a Word from a range, in a string and return corresponding Word from the range

Tags: google-sheets

Column A contains text strings
Range aa:bb (in another sheet):
aa contains keywords
bb contains result-Words

I would like to put a function in for example cell B2 which:
Checks If any of the Words in column aa is in cell A2, and gives the corresponding Word from column bb as a result in cell B2

Cell A2: «my New car»

Cell B2: Red

Col aa: Car, Boat …

Col bb: Red, Green …

Rather not a matrix formula and not a crazy long If function. 
It should not be case sensitive

I think the problem is simple, but difficult to solve with standard Google sheet functions.
Thanks a lot
Leif

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. This question is not a good fit for this site. Did you know  [tag:google-sheets] is this site's most popular and active tag? Because of this, at least we, myself and my alter ego, are super strict, downvoting and closing early and often posts that don't help attract Google Sheets experts.  You might help this site achieve the dream of being a library of high-quality questions and answers by describing the relevant parts of your spreadsheet, showing what you have tried, and showing the most relevant posts and why they didn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` and `regexmatch()` or `search()`, like this:

```
=filter(Sheet2!BB2:BB, regexmatch(Sheet2!AA2:AA, "(?i)" & A2))
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197), [regexmatch()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292) and [search()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154).